# EC2 Security Group inside Security Group

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using security groups inside security groups.

For instance, I would like the `mysql` security group to allow mysql 3306 connections to the `app` server security group.

However, my app server cannot talk to mysql (testing via the mysql cli) but when I specifically add the ip address into the mysql security group, then it works.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit of a long shot, given how little information about your configuration you've provided. However, I had a very eerily similar experience so here goes...

Check that you're using the private ip's and not the public ip's. The public ip will work if you individually specify, but won't with security groups inside security groups.

On the other hand, private ip's are not externally accessible, but then security groups seem to work.

If that still doesn't work, make sure that you have local routes set in your VPC to make sure that the private ip's can work across subnets.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should attach Elastic IP. Then you can use everywhere, If you are using public IP and any case there is the need for restart server, then public Ip will Change.